# Regex filter for file search Java

Tags: java, string

I'm quite new to using regex so I'm having problems with my current code. I created an Abstract File Search that returns a List of Files. I would like this searcher to be filtered by a regex (have ex. the extension it looks for based on a regex filter).

The code of my Abstract Searcher:

```
public abstract class AbstractFileDiscoverer implements IDiscoverer {

    private final Path rootPath;

    AbstractFileDiscoverer(final Path rootPath) {
        super();
        this.rootPath = rootPath;

    }

    protected List<File> findFiles() throws IOException {
        if (!Files.isDirectory(this.rootPath)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path must be a directory");
        }

        List<File> result;

        try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(this.rootPath)) {
            result = walk.filter(p -> !Files.isDirectory(p)).map(p -> p.toFile())
                    .filter(f -> f.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith("")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

I would like the following part to be filtered by the regex, so that only the files that the regex returns as true (for .bat and .sql files) to be collected.

```
result = walk.filter(p -> !Files.isDirectory(p)).map(p -> p.toFile())
                    .filter(f -> f.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith("")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Could anyone help me achieving it?

FIRST EDIT:
I'm aware that `toString().toLowerCase().endsWith("")` always returns true, I actually need the regex there instead of an String with the extension. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: `something.endsWith("")` is always true.

Comment: yes I'm aware, I forgot to mention that there is where I need the regex somehow

Comment: if endswith solves the problem you dont need regex

Comment: There is already something very similar to what you are after. See javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter. You might be able to adopt it into what you are trying to achieve

Comment: One problem with using the `Stream` version of `walk()` is that any exception (i.e. access denied) while in the filter will terminate the entire operation.  With the `FileVisitor` version you can handle any exceptions and continue processing.

Comment: A string doesn't solve my problem, I'm required to use a regex that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this website: https://regexr.com/ and paste the regex `.+(?:.sql|.bat)$` for an explanation.

In code it'd look like this:

```
Stream.of("file1.json", "init.bat", "init.sql", "file2.txt")
            .filter(filename -> filename.matches(".+(?:.sql|.bat)$"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Those periods should be escaped:  `".+\\.(?:sql|bat)$"`

Comment: Hey thanks! your example actually helped me solve the problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a famous quote from Jamie Zawinski about using regular expressions when simpler non-regex code will do.

In your case, I would avoid using a regular expression and would just write a private method:

```
private static boolean hasMatchingExtension(Path path) {
    String filename = path.toString().toLowerCase();
    return filename.endsWith(".bat") || filename.endsWith(".sql");
}
```

Then you can use it in your stream:

```
result = walk.filter(p -> !Files.isDirectory(p)).
    .filter(p -> hasMatchingExtension(p))
    .map(p -> p.toFile())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Consider returning `List<Path>` instead.  The Path class is the modern replacement for the File class, some of whose methods that actually operate on files have design issues.)